# All CSS and JS files are not found on multistore URL in PRESTASHOP

Tags: php, friendly-url, prestashop-1.6

I have enabled multistore option enabled in my prestashop website. I also setup a store named 'abc' and set its url 'http://example.com/abc'. My site home page is runnig well but when I  go to my store url 'http://example.com/abc' it does not load properly due to it couldn't found all js and css file in head tag and it is showing 404 not found for all css and js file in consol.
What can be the problem there.? Thanks for advance help.

Comment: your css and js file urls should start with `/` or have absolute url

Answer (score 4):

1. Open vim `config/settings.inc.php` from config folder
2. Locate the line that contains the `__PS_BASE_URI__` setting, and then update the value with the base URI.

   ```
   If you installed PrestaShop in the document root directory 
   (for example, public_html), 
   then the base URI is /. Alternatively, if you installed PrestaShop 
   in a subdirectory, 
   the base URI is /path, where path represents the folder name. 
   For example, the following line shows 
   the base URI set to the document root directory (/):

   define('__PS_BASE_URI__', '/');

   for subdirectory - define('__PS_BASE_URI__', '/directoryname');
   ```
3. Save Changes.
4. Check this url for more information : http://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/optimization-and-configuration/prestashop2/changing-the-prestashop-url-settings

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for your answer. I have no subdirectory. I have installed my shop in root directory still showing same 404 not found for all js and css in <head> tag on home page of store URL.

Comment: what is your `__PS_BASE_URI__`? Also Can you give me the 404 url?

Comment: I have no LIVE URL. I am doing it on my local server.

Comment: I tell you in detail Actually what I did that I have setup same shop on my pc locahost which main URL is http://demoprestashop/ and on my local server which URL is http://192.168.1.200:8083/. Then I have setup store named "abc" which url is http://demoprestashop/abc/ on my pc localhost and http://192.168.1.200:8083/abc/ on my local server.

Comment: Everything is fine on this url on which the url of js and css file is http://localhost/demoprestashop/abc/themes/default-bootstrap/css/autoload/highdpi.css.  But I am getting 404 error on this URL http://192.168.1.200:8083/abc/themes/default-bootstrap/css/autoload/highdpi.css. I cann't understand why this is happening. I hope you understand it.